# NgRx throws 'TypeError: undefined is not a non-null object' when creating effect

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, web, ngrx

I'm using and learning Angular 15 and I have this injectable class which creates an NgRx effect to store data in a firebase database but it throws undefined.

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions, private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchRecipes = createEffect((): any => {
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(RecipesActions.FETCH_RECIPES),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.http.get<Recipe[]>
          (
            'https://recipebook-re-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/recipes.json',
          )
        }),
        map(recipes => {
          return recipes.map(recipe => {
            return {
              ...recipe,
              ingredients: recipe.ingredients ? recipe.ingredients : []
            };
          });
        }),
        map(recipes => {
          return new RecipesActions.SetRecipes(recipes);
        })
      );
    });
```

I'm a very-beginner in angular and I did this effect following a course, maybe the course is a bit outdated and something is deprecated but I can not figure it out.

EDIT: [Code on GitHub](https://github.com/Danny220/course_project) (can't get [stacblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8nqxdm?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to work sorry)

Comment: [Code on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-52cuum?file=src/environments/environment.production.ts)

Comment: Stackblitz doesn't include above code

Comment: Yea I just spent 50 minutes copying the code from local to stackblitz but it just keeps installing dependencies and doesn't seems to save, perfect

Comment: Perhaps we can help without the stackblitz. At first glance this code looks fine but I get permission denied for above json url. Adding `tap(console.log)` after the `map` with tell you what you're getting from the backend. How are you adding auth to the get request?

Comment: Adding `console.log` to a tap doesn't show up, like the code does not execute. I handle the auth within an auth.effects file (like the code above) wich creates an user variable wich contains the token.

Comment: I uploaded the source to [GitHub](https://github.com/Danny220/course_project) if it's useful

Comment: Move your `map` to the inner observable, just like `return this.http.get<Recipe[]>
          (https://recipebook-re-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/recipes.json').map(recipes => ...)`

Comment: .map doesn't exist, tried to add it through a pipe `.pipe(map(...))` but throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so dumb, the problem was that I didn't return the `this.actions$.pipe()` so it didn't returned anything after all...

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions, private http: HttpClient) {}

fetchRecipes = createEffect((): any => {
   return this.actions$.pipe(...)
});
```

Comment: don't you mean `createEffect((): any => { return this.actions$.pipe...})`. Don't feel too bad, I overlooked this too when examining your code

Comment: Yea sorry, editing it